# My Disk Space is always running low every time I run my Bulk Mailing application

Tags: php, email, sendmail, cpanel

I have an application written in PHP where it send 1000 per 5 mins, I have no problem in sending emails itself however I am always running out of disk space after 2 days! I have no idea what is filling up my disk space. I am newbie on this thing and I really need to figure this out. Is there a way that I can delete those files (if there is) that is filling up my space?, Is it the Mail Queue?  Thank You in advance!

Comment: Is the server that sends the emails the same that receives the thousands of bounced email messages that are returned? If so, link the mailbox to /dev/null - or, clean your spam list by removing the email addresses that are useless.

Answer (score 0):

Check this folder's size /var/spool/exim

> du -sh /var/spool/exim

I guess you mail queue is being filled up.

Comment: is theres a way to disabled the mail queue? thnxs

Comment: You can't, you just need to review the queue and figure out why it's being held rather than going out. Mail queue is just a thing that queue your mail delivery and if they are filled then your mails aren't delivered for some reason that needs to be checked manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access then you will have to run following command to find out exact root cause of these issues, With the following command you will get the all directory disk usages status.

```
cd /
du -sch *
```

Comment: I have clear my mail queue with exim -bp | awk '/^ *[0-9]+[mhd]/{print "exim -Mrm " $3}' | bash and seems that it works. but how can I do this automatically every 2 hours.., and by the way thanks for the help